Laravel Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Collection" not found
I'm encountering an error in my Laravel project, and I need help resolving it. The error message is:
[2024-11-12 06:52:59] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"Illuminate\\Support\\Collection\" not found at /home/playonco/ecomerce.playon24.com.bd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:110)

This occurs when trying to run the application. The error points to the helpers.php file in the Illuminate\Support namespace. It seems that the Collection class isn't being found, which is affecting the logger setup.

Note: I am facing problem into C-Panel.

Does anyone know why this error is occurring, or what steps I should take to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Which version of Laravel are you using? Have you tried running composer du (aka dump-autoload)?


remove your vendor folder
run this command composer install --optimize-autoloader
then try these commands
php artisan cache:clear php artisan config:clear php artisan view:clear

hope that it will resolved your issue

I have solved it by updating it to C-panel PHP version 7.3 for the specific project.
